# How to change boot screen name?

Tags: boot, screen, customization

I want to change the name 'ubuntu 12.04LTS' in boot screen to some other name.How can I do dat?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Plymouth Manager a GUI tool: http://handytutorial.com/change-the-boot-splash-screen-theme-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04/

Comment: I think he is talking about the text at the bottom-left corner of the `lightdm` screen (i.e. log-in screen), and not splash.